# Is there a short term for a banner ad displayed on all pages of a website?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

I'm translating a media kit table with banner ad rates, and in one of the cells of said table there's a pithy short expression in Russian saying that the banner is to be displayed in its exact position (above News Feed) on each of the site's pages, unlike other banners.

When you're paying for other banners, you're negotiating on which pages of the site they will be displayed, but with this "throughout" option ("**throughout banner**" or **[сквозной](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9) баннер** in Russian), the banner is displayed on every page of the site.

I'm wondering how to put it in English and fit the description in the table cell. Will "all-pages banner" be okay? Will it be understood by the native speaker, or will a footnote be necessary to explain what an "all-pages" banner is?

I've found an interesting related term, "Run-Of-Site (ROS) banner", but that's not quite it.

Maybe "[site-wide banner](http://www.translatorscafe.com/tcterms/RU/thQuestion.aspx?id=58200)" would be better.

Comment: A common header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To judge from [this website](http://www.patsfans.com/advertise/mediacenter/banner_advertising.php), the term you are looking for might be "Nonrotating Top Banner Ad." Another possible name, based on the wording used on [this website](http://www.ktox1340.com/ktox/advertise-online/), is "Top-of-Page Nonrotating Banner Ad."

Normally, banner ads displayed on major website pages rotate with four or five other ads in each display-ad space, so that only one is visible on a particular click-through. To appear on all pages of a website on every click-through, an ad must be permanent and nonrotating. The technical name for a banner ad that appears at the top or bottom of a page appears to be "Top [or Bottom] Banner Ad."